# Cat isn't working on certain files

Tags: android, bash, cpu, cat

I'm trying to read some files on an Android device using cat.  Specifically, I want to see

```
"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq",
"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq",
"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq", and
"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
```

When I use the terminal I have installed on the device, it works fine for cpu0, but tells me I have an "invalid argument" when I try cpu1, 2, or 3.  I have confirmed that the files are there with ls, and that they are not directories by trying to cd to them.  Can anyone shed some light on why I can't read these files?  Thank you!

Comment: do you find anything by doing `ls -l /sys/devices/system/cpu/*`. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I get a whole bunch of info.  It's too long to include here, but I did some other searching and found that if I ls -l in 
*/cpu0/cpufreq/ I get the same exact stuff as in */cpu1/cpufreq except for the second line. CPU0 reads (-r--r--r-- system   root         4096 2014-02-04 17:26 cpuinfo_cur_freq) while CPU1 reads (-r-------- root     root         4096 2014-02-04 17:31 cpuinfo_cur_freq).  Is this the problem?

Comment: Are you running your problem commands a root? I guess not, and yes, having a file with perms '-r-------' will be difficult to read, but I would expect a different error message, not invalid argument. You have your question tagged with `sh`. Your really using `bash` or `ksh` or something else right? Best to change you tag to reflect the true shell you're using as then you'll get more people looking at your problem. Right now, I don't see any way I can help on this. :-( ... Good luck.

Comment: I get the same error when I try running it with root as I did when I ran it without root.  Though I might add that the file that has -r------ isn't the one I was trying to read anyway; it is related to scaling frequency, but not the same.  And yes, I suppose I am using bash, my mistake, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Are you really using bash???  While not impossible to install, that's somewhat atypical on Android, where the default shell is a simple re-implementation of sh, and the most common alternative would be a busybox shell.

Comment: In terms of the question itself, you should know that these are not *really* "files" but instead an interface to the kernel, which generates their content on-the-fly.  It may be that there are issues with the implementation - they probably aren't considered a very "important" feature on a typical end-user device.